# Get the response from the dispatch - React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

How can I get a response back from the dispatch action to the component and get the values in the context.

index.jsx :

```
    componentWillMount() {
        this.context.store.dispatch(getConfigSettings());
    }
```

Dispatch calls :

```
export function getConfigSettings(params) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestConfig());
        admin.getConfig(params,
            (response) => {
                return dispatch(receivedConfig(response));
            },
            (error) => {
                return dispatch(failedConfig(error));
            }
        );
    };
}

export function getConfig(params, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    const url = `${process.env}/admin/data`;
    return $.get(url,
        (response) => {
            onSuccess(response);
        }).fail((error) => {
        onFailure(error);
    });
}
```

Reducer :

```
import {
    request,
    received,
    failed
} from '../actions/actions';

const defaultState = Immutable.fromJS({
    data: Immutable.fromJS([]),
    loading: true,
    error: false
});

const reducer = createReducer({
    [request]: (state, res) => {
        return state.set('loading', true)
            .set('error', false)
    },
    [received]: (state, res) => {
        return state.set('data', Immutable.fromJS(res))
            .set('loading', false)
            .set('error', false); 
    },
    [failed]: (state, res) => {
        return state.set('data', Immutable.fromJS({}))
            .set('loading', false)
            .set('error', true)
    }
}, defaultState);

export default reducer;
```

I have checked the response has the correct value. But how to access that value in the index.jsx
I have to display those values in the table.

Comment: Is your reducer updating with the action payload?

Comment: mapStateToProps() targeting the specific properties being updated as a result of `receivedConfig()`. Access those as props in the component render.

Comment: Is there any other way to access than using the mapStateToProps. and accessing it directly from the context store

Answer (score 2):

While you really should just utilize mapStateToProps() to retrieve the data you need from the store, you can return a Promise that resolves the response or rejects the data as follows:

```
export function getConfigSettings(params) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestConfig());

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          admin.getConfig(params,
              (response) => {
                  dispatch(receivedConfig(response));
                  return resolve(response);
                  // or return resolve(dispatch(receivedConfig(response)));
              },
              (error) => {
                  dispatch(failedConfig(error));
                  return reject(error);
                  // or return reject(dispatch(failedConfig(error)));
              }
          );
        }
    };
}
```

Then in the component you can access the resolved response or rejected error using `then()` and `catch()`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.context.store.dispatch(getConfigSettings())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7huxky) in action.

I'd really recommend looking into something Promise based for making HTTP calls such as [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to avoid needing callbacks. `redux-thunk` works really well with promises.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This one works - somehow I am using generic pages which is not allowing me to use connect to pass on the data as redux- thunk does. Is there any way to get the value from reducer the same way we got the response from action ?

Comment: @PSDebugger I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you mean to get the data/response exactly as it is passed to the reducer? If so `return resolve(dispatch(receivedConfig(response)));`. I'd say it's a fairly big issue that you cannot for some reason use `connect()` in your components. This is going to cause a lot of issues doing simple things like getting state from the store.